# Firebase web push notifications

Tags: firebase, web, push-notification, notifications, service-worker

Hey guys I am using firebase push notifications in the web application, I am showing the notification via the service worker as mentioned in the firebase documentation.
 the problem is when I open the browser , I see multiple push notifications stacked upon one another  , as its very annoying to see many push notifications , is there any way to combine push notifications into one, based on some attribute.

Comment: Please add whatever code you are using

Comment: sorry buddy ,can't add the code but the service worker code is same as mentioned in firebase documentation.

Comment: I guess nobody will be able to help you then

Comment: don't downvote if you cant help

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot group them.  That is why many users tend to turn off notifications in their mobile devices because it is annoying.  You have to follow the basic principles of push notifications.

- It must be timely
- It must be relevant to the users